# JSF2 flash scope cookie

Tags: flash, cookies, jsf-2.2

We are using apache `myfaces 2.1.14` as JSF2 implementation in our project.

I have found below two cookies getting added as :

```
oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN   
oam.Flash.REDIRECT
```

I am able to get purpose of first one. 
But I am not able to understand the purpose of `"oam.Flash.REDIRECT"` cookie.

The questions are :

- What is the purpose of this cookie ?
- When is this cookie added ?
- Is it related with first cookie ?
- It must be related with flash scope.So if flash scope is disabled  , 
  will it  vanish ?

I have searched on public forum but didn't get information about this cookie . All forums talk about first one but no information is available on second one ?

Can anybody please help ?

Answer (score 0):

oam.Flash.REDIRECT is a cookie that works for Flash.setRedirect(...). The basic idea is the navigation algorithm (NavigationHandler) indicate whether a request is a redirect and this activates some special steps inside Flash object to preserve the scope between the current request and the next one. Both cookies are part of the default algorithm for Flash scope, but each one has its own purpose.

If you disable Flash scope, the cookies will disappear. In MyFaces 2.2, ClientWindow API is now available, so oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN cookie was replaced by a new algorithm that uses the client window id and http session object, and there is also a new cleanup algorithm for this scope (recently added). oam.Flash.REDIRECT is still in use (latest version at this time is 2.2.6).

If you have further question please ask on [MyFaces users mailing list](http://myfaces.apache.org/mail-lists.html).